# Angularx Social Login - issue

Tags: angular, angular-social-login

I have integrated the AngularSocial Login in the angular/.net core application using
(Ref: https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login ).
Having Angular 8 in dev environment. There are no issue in npm start.
On running localhost, getting the exception from browser and the following details.

angularx-social-login.js:342

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Injectable')
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/angularx-social-login/fesm2015/angularx-social-login.js?:342)
at Module../node_modules/angularx-social-login/fesm2015/angularx-social-login.js (vendor~main.js:107)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:80)
at eval (webpack:///./src/app/login/login.component.ts?:17)
at Object../src/app/login/login.component.ts (main.js:589)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:80)
at eval (webpack:///./src/app/login/index.ts?:6)
at Object../src/app/login/index.ts (main.js:566)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:80)
at eval (webpack:///./src/app/app.routing.ts?:5)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When trying to use social login from angular/. net core code getting this exception.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: compiler.compileFactoryDeclaration is not a function
    at Module.ɵɵngDeclareFactory (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js?:33525)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/angularx-social-login/fesm2015/angularx-social-login.js?:342)
    at Module../node_modules/angularx-social-login/fesm2015/angularx-social-login.js (vendor~main.js:107)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:80)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/app/login/login.component.ts?:17)